# Why tor allow only root to connect to control port?

Tags: configuration

I have enabled control port, using password authentication.
I run this

```
telnet localhost 9051
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

With root is ok, I can send commands (autenticate, getinfo, etc.)
As normal user the connection is "freezed" and no command run is possible.
I also add my user to tor group, nothing change.
Those are settings in /etc/tor/torrc

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword *****
```

What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the local host configuration. The user-based connection issues on a tor side are only taking place when you are using Unix socket, not TCP socket

Comment: Thanks I have configured tor for using socket instead of tcp

Comment: TCP socket works fine as well - just make sure you're using localhost **by IP**